# Method is expecting not parameters but I need to pass an integer

Tags: java, class, methods

I have to pass the integer "i" through the parameter of getCoursePar .However i'm getting an error that says i cant pass an integer through this method. Im unable to change this the method as this is a class task and suppose to make this code work, Any tips?

The  get scores method is present in one class. while the getCoursePar is defined in another class. I'm calling the getCoursepar method in the class with the getscores method.

```
 public int[] getScores() {
    for (int i = 0; i < holeScores.length; i++) {
        holeScores[i] -= Course.getCoursePar(i);
    } return holeScores;
}


public int getCoursePar() {
        coursePar = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < holes.length;i++){
        coursePar += holes[i];
    } return coursePar;
```

Comment: Why do you believe you have to pass an parameter `i` to `getCoursePar()` ?

Comment: Well it i need to pass the integer "i" through because i need to count the number hole-score there are. With where the method is defined in getCoursePar i'm unable to change the parameter because for my assignment it is suppose to match with a UML diagram. There might be another way to do this which i'm all ears for

Comment: To make it short - if you cannot change the signature of `getCoursePar()`, then you cannot pass parameters to it. Judging from the code you provided alone, which is little information, what you are supposed to do is retrieve information from `getCoursePar()`. This information is a sum of numbers stored in `holes`, a variable you also presumably have no access to - at least not whithin the code you provided. You then need to do something with this information in your own function.